# Дублируется часть URL

Tags: php, mvc, url, маршрутизация, route

Здравствуйте. Дублируется часть URL при переходе на ссылки, отличные от корневой. Мой сайт расположен не в корневом каталоге, а в отдельной папке.

Вот адрес главной станицы:

**http://localhost/testTaskForCodeIt/**

Вот перехожу первый раз на страницу регистрации:

**http://localhost/testTaskForCodeIt/user/register** (пока что все нормально)

Вот нажимаю еще раз кнопку регистрации:

**http://localhost/testTaskForCodeIt/user/user/register**

И вот тут начинает дублироваться часть **user**

**.htacces**

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

**файл с роутами:**

```
return array(

    'user/register' => 'user/register',
    'user/login' => 'user/login',
    'user/logout' => 'user/logout',

    '' => 'application/index',
);
```

Вот сам  роутер:

```
<?php

class Router
{

private $routes;

public function __construct()
{
    $routesPath = ROOT . '/config/routes.php';
    $this->routes = include($routesPath);
}

/**
 * Returns request string
 */
private function getURI()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    }
}

public function run()
{
    // Получить строку запроса
    $uri = $this->getURI();

    // Проверить наличие такого запроса в routes.php
    foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {


        // Сравниваем $uriPattern и $uri
        if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {



            //var_dump(strpos($uri, $uriPattern));

            // Получаем внутренний путь из внешнего согласно правилу.
            $internalRoute = preg_replace("~^$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

            // Определить контроллер, action, параметры

            $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

            $controllerName = array_shift($segments) . 'Controller';
            $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

            $actionName = 'action' . ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

            $parameters = $segments;

            // Подключить файл класса-контроллера
            $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' .
                    $controllerName . '.php';

            if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                include_once($controllerFile);
            }

            // Создать объект, вызвать метод (т.е. action)
            $controllerObject = new $controllerName;


            $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);


            if ($result) {
                break;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

}

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что можно сделать в данной ситуации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну тут все очевидно:

```
'user/register' => 'user/register',
```

доступно объясняя, без переднего слеша - строка дописывается в текущую.

Вам нужно указывать полный путь:

```
/testTaskForCodeIt/user/user/register
```

Обратите внимание на передний слеш.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а если у меня текущая дериктория, где расположен проект может меняться, как мне тогда прописывать полный путь? И где его прописывать? В списке, где я объявляю все роуты? или только тогда, когда использую данный роут в html-коде?

Comment: Я просто немного не понимаю как должен выглядеть абсолютный путь в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Мои телепатические способности подсказывают мне, что в вашем коде надо искать:

1. `header('Location: user/register')` в коде контроллера;
2. `<form action='user/register'>` в коде представления.

Если вы располагаете код не в корне, то вы не можете себе позволить относительные пути. Вы должны везде использовать только **абсолютные пути**.

Comment: У меня проблема как раз с обращением в коде представления.  Я немного не понимаю, как надо абсолютный путь прописать в данном случае? Надо прописывать с учетом того, что имя текущей директории, где находится проект, может изменится.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за советы. Вот мое решение, если кому-то пригодится.

Router.php

```
<?php

class Router
{

    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routesPath = ROOT . '/config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }

    /**
     * Returns request string
     */
    public static function getURI()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
            return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        // Получить строку запроса
        $uri = $this->getURI();
        $url = [];
        $url = explode('/', $uri);
        // Вырезаю название своей текущей папки
        $direct = array_shift($url);
        // Создаю константу с названием этой папки
        define('DIRECT', $direct);

        $route = implode('/', $url);
        // Проверить наличие такого запроса в routes.php
        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {


            // Сравниваем $uriPattern и $uri
            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $route)) {

                // Получаем внутренний путь из внешнего согласно правилу.
                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~^$uriPattern~", $path, $route);

                // Определить контроллер, action, параметры

                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments) . 'Controller';
                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                $actionName = 'action' . ucfirst(array_shift($segments));

                $parameters = $segments;

                // Подключить файл класса-контроллера
                $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' .
                        $controllerName . '.php';

                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    include_once($controllerFile);
                }

                // Создать объект, вызвать метод (т.е. action)
                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;


                $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);


                if ($result) {
                    break;
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

Далее использую эту константу для создания абсолютного пути:

```
<li><a href="/<?php echo DIRECT ?>/user/register">Register</a></li>
<li><a href= "/<?php echo DIRECT ?>/user/login">Login</a></li>
```

Comment: 1) немножко не правильная логика для роута.
2) В следующий раз, когда в комментарии обращаетесь не к автору вопроса, ставьте @<NICK> (В моем случае: "@Manitikyl, .....") чтобы я смог получить уведомление о вашем комментарии и помочь вам.

Comment: @Manitikyl, спасибо большое) Я с этими всеми фичами еще не разобралась. А можно Вас тогда спросить, как бы Вы переделали роут? Мне лично не нравится, как я вставляю имя текущей директории в путь. Но я пока и не думала об этой задаче глобально.

Comment: тут описывать правильность роута долго и не хватит символов) Вы можете либо сами посмотреть реализации роутов, либо написать мне личное сообщение, мы с вами свяжемся каким либо способом и я вам расскажу.